# How do I create a new instance of an object when using the module pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I am using Javascript's "module pattern" to create a new class. Here's what I have:

```
var Car = (function() {
    var internal = {};

    internal.init = function(color, brand) {
        internal.color = color;
        internal.brand = brand;

        return internal;
    }

    return internal;
})();
```

However, when I create new instances it seems to all return the same data:

```
var ferrari = Car.init('red', 'ferrari');
var audi = Car.init('blue', 'audi');

console.log(ferrari.color + ' ' + ferrari.brand); // --> "blue audi"
console.log(audi.color + ' ' + audi.brand);       // --> "blue audi"
```

How do I go about fixing it so that it returns the data it was initialized with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate a class in your `init` method.
You should create a class within your module and instantiate it in your `init`.

This should do it:

```
var Car = (function() {
    var internal = {};

    var theClass = function(color, brand) {

        this.color = color;
        this.brand = brand;

    }

    internal.init = function(color, brand) {
       return new theClass(color, brand);
    }

    return internal;
})();
```

Please refer to this: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Comment: Glad it helps. I'm a fan of module pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your are mixing some concepts, to fix your problem objectively:

```
var Car = (function() {
    var internal = {};

    internal.init = function(color, brand) {
        var car = {}
        car.color = color;
        car.brand = brand;

        return car;
    }

    return internal;
})();
```

You did something like this:

1. Created an anonymous function and executed it. The execution did:
2. Create **one** object and assigned to an variable called internal.
3. Create an function on **that single instance** to change **itself** and return **itself again**.
4. Return that **single instance**.

As you can see, calling init twice is only changing the same object, not creating a new one.

You must create a **new instance** every time to achieve what your expect. Anyway, give a read about the **new** operator and **prototypes** to get a better understanding about the subject.